# Safari: Can't find variable: HTMLUnknownElement

Tags: javascript, dom, safari

According to MDN, `HTMLUnknownElement` is supported by all browsers including Safari: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement.

But I am getting `Can't find variable: HTMLUnknownElement` when I test `myVar instance of HTMLUnknownElement`. Also just typing `HTMLUnknownElement` in Safari (hard to find) console and pressing enter throws this error.

I am using latest Safari 5.1.7 on Windows 8.1 x64.

- Is it a known issue?
- Is there a workaround?

Comment: typo that you wrote "HTMLUnknownEelement " ?, should be "HTMLUnknownElement"

Comment: Safari hasn't been supported on Windows for years. Apple have abandoned it. I wouldn't make it a target platform. (Sarai/OS X and Mobile Safari/iOS are another matter, but have much newer versions available).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MDN is referring to a vaguely-recent version of Safari, as support for `HTMLUnknownElement` was [added in Safari 6](http://compatibility.shwups-cms.ch/de/home?&property=HTMLUnknownElement)*. As [Quentin said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991044/safari-cant-find-variable-htmlunknownelement#comment46230378_28991044), Apple gave up on Windows years ago, and Safari 5.1.7 is nearly **three years** out of date (current version of Safari is 8.x).

There's no need to target Safari for Windows. The "workaround" is to just use Safari on iOS or Mac OS X, and use a vaguely-recent version.

---

* You have to use the "choose browsers" button and select Safari 5.1.7 and Safari 6.0.2 in order to see when it was added.